# Chainlink Automation programmatic upkeep registration not showing on https://automation.chain.link/mumbai

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

i have managed call the register() function and the events are now properly formated also on polygonscan.

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x3aa72ddf8b93248bad0b86354f2f690b2c04704961fdb63154c42189269cac3f#eventlog

The transaction emits a RegistrationApproved() event confirming the registration, but it does not show on https://automation.chain.link/mumbai .

I have also noticed that the registry address in the automation web interface differs from the one in the documentation

The address from https://automation.chain.link/mumbai: 0xE16Df59B887e3Caa439E0b29B42bA2e7976FD8b2

The address from https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/supported-networks/#configurations: 0x02777053d6764996e594c3E88AF1D58D5363a2e6

I did try improve the format of the register function, but it does look to me that it is properly formated.

I have also noticed that the registry address in the automation web interface differs from the one in the documentation

The address from https://automation.chain.link/mumbai: 0xE16Df59B887e3Caa439E0b29B42bA2e7976FD8b2

The address from https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/supported-networks/#configurations: 0x02777053d6764996e594c3E88AF1D58D5363a2e6